# MSSQL: Can't restore with Time of Point

Tags: sql-server

I have created a full mssql backup file and now i want to restore it to a certain point of time. But i can't.

I select the device backup and the list of "Restore items" shows. Then i specify the "Point of time", but then the items in the "Restore items" list gets blank and i can't select a database to restore.

The backup contains the log file. When i restore the backup without the "Point of time" option the file is also restored.

Is there something i need to enable when i make the backup? Or what is doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point-In-Time restores need a backup that contains the DB log. If you take a simple backup only, there is no information what rows are changed over time. For backups that can restore to any point in time, set the database to the Full Recovery Model, this includes the log in backups. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173531%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: The backup contains the log file. When i restore the backup without the "Point of time" option the file is also restored.

Comment: @Poku So the Recovery Model is set to "Full" already? Also, because your DB seems to be a testing scene, did you alter the db before and after the desired Point-In-Time?

Comment: Yes, Recovery Model is set to FULL and there have been modification in the database before and after my desired Point-In-Time. I'm using a live db scene, I just renamed the .bak file for security reasons.

Comment: There's a difference between being able to restore the physical log file and having a transaction log backup to restore.  In order to get point in time recovery, you need to have issued the 'backup log' command after having taken your full backup (and be in either full or bulk logged recovery model).  Then when you restore, you'll restore your full backup and any transaction log backups since to get to the point that you want to recover to.  HTH.